# Make programmatically presentation

Tags: javascript, html, presentation

I would like to know if there is a way to create presentation (other than prezi's or powerpoint's) programmatically ?

I mean maybe a library or something exists in a specific language (html/css or javascript would be great) ?
Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think  Impress should do the trick.

http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/#/overview

Comment: it is better to use it with chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest to check http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/ as well.